# Multilevel dropdown not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, haml

I am new to front end development.
I am trying to add a multi level dropdown menu using bootstrap. Here is the Haml code that I am using which I found on the internet.
I am able to get the first level of dropdown when I click on `Header 4`, however if I click on `Sub Heading 1`, it does not show me the 2nd level drop down menu rather closes the parent drop down as well.

```
%nav.navbar.navbar-inverse.sidebar
  .container-fluid
    %a.navbar-brand{:href => "#"} API Reference
    #bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
      %ul.nav.navbar-nav
        %li.active
          %a{:href => "#"}
            Header 1
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"}
            Header 2
        %li
          %a{:href => "#"}
            Header 3
        %li.dropdown
          %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
            Header 4
            %span.caret
          %ul.dropdown-menu
            %li.dropdown
              %a.dropdown-toggle{"data-toggle" => "dropdown", :href => "#"}
                Sub Heading 1
                %span.caret
              %ul.dropdown-menu
                %li
                  %a{:href => "#"} Sub Sub Heading 1
                %li
                  %a{:href => "#"} Sub Sub Heading 2
                %li
                  %a{:href => "#"} Sub Sub Heading 3
            %li
              %a{:href => "#"} Sub heading 2

.main
  / Main content goes here..
```

The code gives the following output:

[image]

Not sure, how do I get it to work. I have not used Javascript in the existing solution.

If someone is not familiar with haml, you can use the http://htmltohaml.com/ to see the code in html

Answer (score 0):

You are using `dropdown-menu` class only, but you should use `dropdown-submenu` also.

For example, see: https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h